# How to override element.style in css (tried and couldn't get to work)

Tags: css

On my wordpress site I am trying to override some element.style attributes that found using inspect element.    ([Here is what I am seeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSfx6.png))

I'm trying to override

```
element.style {
height: 400px;
top: -400px;
}
```

and replace it with

```
element.style {
height: 100px;
top: -300px;
}
```

What I have added to the style.css is below, but it hasn't changed anything.

```
div.nslider-arrow-navigation a.nslider-arrow-right {
 height: 100px !important;
 top: -300px !important;
}

div.nslider-arrow-navigation a.nslider-arrow-left {
 height: 100px  !important;
 top: -300px  !important;
}
```

What should I do to fix it?

Comment: It's possible those styles are being modified via JavaScript after the page loads...

Comment: Thanks for replying.  Do you know what the javascript that is changing it might look like, or where it would be located?  Just wondering so I can do a ctrl + f search to find the code.

Comment: In the screenshot you show I can't see the `!important` rule being applied..

Comment: That is what I added to my style.css file

Comment: Why is it `element.style {}`? Shouldn't it just be `element {}`?

Comment: element.style means that it is hard-coded in the html somewhere

Comment: Thanks, oddly enough when I checked it today it apparently the changes have worked even though the inspect tool isn't showing it.